# yii make multiple language url in Arabic and English site

Tags: php, yii

after long search , i want to make multiple language website folders
like:  ar / en

```
http://localhost/yii/en
```

or

```
 http://localhost/yii/ar
```

the right way 
- create  folder
or
-change url depends on lang session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case Yii has very good wiki: 
[SEO conform multilingual urls and language selector widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/)

1. Extend the CUrlManager

Create the file 'components/UrlManager.php' with the content:

```
<?php
class UrlManager extends CUrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($route,$params=array(),$ampersand='&')
    {
        if (!isset($params['language'])) {
            if (Yii::app()->user->hasState('language'))
                Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->user->getState('language');
            else if(isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']))
                Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']->value;
            $params['language']=Yii::app()->language;
        }
        return parent::createUrl($route, $params, $ampersand);
    }
}
?>
```

2. Edit your Controller

Add the following code to 'components/Controller.php':

```
<?php
public function __construct($id,$module=null){
    parent::__construct($id,$module);
    // If there is a post-request, redirect the application to the provided url of the selected language 
    if(isset($_POST['language'])) {
        $lang = $_POST['language'];
        $MultilangReturnUrl = $_POST[$lang];
        $this->redirect($MultilangReturnUrl);
    }
    // Set the application language if provided by GET, session or cookie
    if(isset($_GET['language'])) {
        Yii::app()->language = $_GET['language'];
        Yii::app()->user->setState('language', $_GET['language']); 
        $cookie = new CHttpCookie('language', $_GET['language']);
        $cookie->expire = time() + (60*60*24*365); // (1 year)
        Yii::app()->request->cookies['language'] = $cookie; 
    }
    else if (Yii::app()->user->hasState('language'))
        Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->user->getState('language');
    else if(isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']))
        Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']->value;
}
public function createMultilanguageReturnUrl($lang='en'){
    if (count($_GET)>0){
        $arr = $_GET;
        $arr['language']= $lang;
    }
    else 
        $arr = array('language'=>$lang);
    return $this->createUrl('', $arr);
}
?>
```

**Note**: If we don't set Yii::app()->language explicitly for each request, it will be equal to its default value set in the confg file. If it is not set in the config file, it will be equal to the value Yii::app()->sourceLanguage, which defaults to 'en_us'.
You can set default values for the language and sourceLanguage of your application in your config file with

```
'sourceLanguage'=>'en',
'language'=>'de',
```

3. Build a Language Selector Widget

Create the file 'components/widgets/LanguageSelector.php' with the content:

```
<?php
class LanguageSelector extends CWidget
{
    public function run()
    {
        $currentLang = Yii::app()->language;
        $languages = Yii::app()->params->languages;
        $this->render('languageSelector', array('currentLang' => $currentLang, 'languages'=>$languages));
    }
}
?>
```

Create the file 'components/widgets/views/languageSelector.php' with the content:

```
<div id="language-select">
<?php 
    if(sizeof($languages) < 4) {
        // Render options as links
        $lastElement = end($languages);
        foreach($languages as $key=>$lang) {
            if($key != $currentLang) {
                echo CHtml::link(
                     $lang, 
                     $this->getOwner()->createMultilanguageReturnUrl($key));
            } else echo '<b>'.$lang.'</b>';
            if($lang != $lastElement) echo ' | ';
        }
    }
    else {
        // Render options as dropDownList
        echo CHtml::form();
        foreach($languages as $key=>$lang) {
            echo CHtml::hiddenField(
                $key, 
                $this->getOwner()->createMultilanguageReturnUrl($key));
        }
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('language', $currentLang, $languages,
            array(
                'submit'=>'',
            )
        ); 
        echo CHtml::endForm();
    }
?>
</div>
```

4. Put the Widget on your Site

Add the following code into the header-div in 'views/layouts/main.php'

```
<div  id="language-selector" style="float:right; margin:5px;">
    <?php 
        $this->widget('application.components.widgets.LanguageSelector');
    ?>
</div>
```

5. Edit your Config File

Apply the following changes/additions to the file 'config/main.php':

```
<?php
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'request'=>array(
        'enableCookieValidation'=>true,
        'enableCsrfValidation'=>true,
    ),
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.components.UrlManager',
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<language:(de|tr|en)>/' => 'site/index',
            '<language:(de|tr|en)>/<action:(contact|login|logout)>/*' => 'site/<action>',
            '<language:(de|tr|en)>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<language:(de|tr|en)>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<language:(de|tr|en)>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
),
'params'=>array(
    'languages'=>array('tr'=>'Türkçe', 'en'=>'English', 'de'=>'Deutsch'),
),
?>
```

We declare our new class 'UrlManager' as the class to be used by the urlManager component, and prefix / to the keys of our rules array.

Answer (score 0):

first you can create the language file in

> protected\messages\ar
>   Blockquote the file name should be translation.php, The language file contains array key and values pairs

```html
<? return array (
"Why Join?"=>"Warum Mitglied werden?");
```

After that you can access the url http://localhost/projects/ar.
Keep in mind the selected language should be stord in session